# REST API: append 'bulk' to api to create bulk create on same resource?

Tags: rest

I have a resource `class`. I need two APIs :

1. bulk create classes
2. create one class.

In the REST standards should I create 2 APIs:

1. `/classes/bulk/` --- for bulk create
2. `/classes/` --- to create one class.

This approach doesn't seem to REStFul to me or is it?
Is it more RESTful to use query param for this : `/classes?type=bulk` ?

Also, the processing logic and the response schema for 200 is different for the bulk and the non bulk call

Comment: REST isn't a standard, just an architectural design in order to decouple clients from servers and make the former one more tolerant towards changes and give the latter one the freedom to evolve without having to fear breaking clients. To achive such strong benefits a couple of contstraints have to be followed concisely, i.e. HATEAOS support and strong focus on media-types and content negotiation as well as [avoiding typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)

Comment: @RomanVottner: but isnt it RESTful that each path in the URL should be a resource.

Comment: Not necessarily! The segments in the URI are actually not related per se. The URI as a whole is a pointer to a resource. Of course you are free to structure multiple URIs that in total act like each segment of that URI points to a resource and therefore form a kind of resouce-path. Nevertheless, clients shouldn't parse URIs and just use URIs as a whole and sense its intention from the accompanying link-relation name. This make clients more robust to changes and allow APIs to change their URI structure without breaking clients

Answer (score 1):

> This approach doesn't seem to RESTful to me or is it?

The URI spelling is not relevant in the REST architectural. Appending `/bulk` to the URI or not won't make your application more RESTful or not.

---

Alternatively to use `/bulk` in the URI, you could use the same URI for handling the creation of one or multiple resources. Consider that your resource is a *message*. Then you could have the following:

```json
POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
  "to": "John"
  "content": "Hi"
}
```

```json
POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

[
  { 
    "to": "John"
    "content": "Hi"
  },
  { 
    "to": "James"
    "content": "Hey"
  },
  { 
    "to": "Sarah"
    "content": null
  }
]
```

It's also important to keep in mind whether the operation will be *atomic* or not. If one message contains invalid data, you may or may not reject the whole request.

If the operation *is atomic*, you can use [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) or [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) to report invalid data. If the operation *is not atomic* you could use [`207`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.1) to report the result of the operation of each resource.